# Isolate object against heat

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, heat-conduction

I'm trying to reduce the temperature inside of a small water tank that is standing outside. It slowly heats up over the day caused by the ambient air temperatures.

Is it possible to slow down the heating of the water inside the tank over the day with some form of isolation, while not reducing the time it needs to cool down in the evening? Preferred something I could wrap the tank in, like a foil or wrap.

Comment: Perhaps a heat pipe can do the job.

Comment: If you have a breeze, and you don't mind losing some water, you could use [evaporative cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler).

Comment: I would like to use something like a foil or wrap that I could put around it.

Comment: This is really more of an engineering question.  There's perhaps a dozen answers I could give, each of which depends on the specific details of the apparatus you're designing and the engineering requirements you are levying on it.  I thought about trying to answer this from a physics perspective, to cover all of them as a Physics.SE question, but the physics of each methodology is so different, there's not one physics answer I could give.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a hollow sleeve with shiny foil on the outside, that encircles the tank and entrains an air gap between the sleeve and the tank walls. this will shield it from the sun and slow down the daytime heating rate. Then at night, you either pull off the sleeve to expose the tank so it cools down quickly, or turn on a small air fan that blows cool night air into the gap to carry off the heat.